# Apache Beam + Apache Flink + AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, apache-beam

I am trying to write a simple word count example in Apache Beam and run it using direct runner, flink runner and spark runner. My input and output are on AWS S3 and my Flink/Spark cluster are running on local machine using docker.

The code runs fine for direct runner as well as for spark runner, but I get:

> org.apache.beam.sdk.io.aws.s3.S3ResourceId cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.io.LocalResourceId

error when running flink runner.

I had to make absolutely no configuration changes for spark and just configuring AWSOptions in beam code worked smoothly. But the same code gives the above error with Flink. So, I tried to configure Flink for reading/writing from S3 using instructions from https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/aws.html#shaded-hadooppresto-s3-file-systems-recommended but it didn't help.

Looking at the error message its clear that Flink is not configured properly for S3 file system but I couldn't find any way yet to resolve this.

Any pointers??? Here is my main method:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
{
    S3WordCountOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(S3WordCountOptions.class);
    options.as(AwsOptions.class).setAwsCredentialsProvider(getAWSCredentialProvider(options.getAwsKey(), options.getAwsSecret()));
    options.as(AwsOptions.class).setAwsRegion(options.getAwsRegion());
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

    p.apply("ReadLines", TextIO.read().from(options.getInputFile()))
    .apply(FlatMapElements
            .into(TypeDescriptors.strings())
            .via((String word) -> Arrays.asList(word.split("[^\\p{L}]+"))))
    .apply(Filter.by((String word) -> !word.isEmpty()))
    .apply(Count.perElement())
    .apply(MapElements
            .into(TypeDescriptors.strings())
            .via((KV<String, Long> wordCount) -> wordCount.getKey() + ": " + wordCount.getValue()))
     .apply("WriteCounts", TextIO.write().to(options.getOutput()));

    p.run().waitUntilFinish();
}
```

Comment: Were you ever able to get this working, I'm running into a similar issue currently